# 7zip Unzip Folder, rename contents, rezip folder

Tags: batch-file, 7zip

I have a list of thousands of folders. Inside these folders are zip files. I need to unzip the folders, rename the contents of the zipped folder to "zipped folder name" & "_" & "File Name" and then rezip the unzipped folder. I have tried this batch code but it does not work as all it does is create a folder with the zipped file name. Any help is appreciated!    I have 7zip and powershell as the main options I work with but I will do whatever will work.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
for %%z in (*.zip) do (
    if not exist "%%~nz" md "%%~nz"
    7za e -o"%%~nz" "%%~fz"
    for %%f in ("%%~nz\*") do ren "%%~ff" "%%~nz - %%~nxf"
)
```

Comment: 'I have tried this batch code but it does not work.' is not an adequate problem description; please [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49235928/edit) providing sufficient information for those of us not sat at your computer to better understand what problems are occurring. The usual way of doing that is to turn `echo`ing on and run the script from a `cmd.exe` window so that you can clearly see it's output, _and if necessary copy it into your question_.

Comment: I have updated the question with the output from my batch file.

Comment: No output, from running your batch file appears to have been added. Also, is `7za.exe` also in the same directory as the `.zip` files?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing an archiving step.
I would suggest putting modified archives into a separate directory, so in case something goes wrong your original files will stay intact.

This is the possible code:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
set OUTPUT_DIR=..\output
md "%OUTPUT_DIR%"
for %%z in (*.zip) do (
    if not exist "%%~nz" md "%%~nz"
    7za e -o"%%~nz" "%%~fz"
    for %%f in ("%%~nz\*") do ren "%%~ff" "%%~nz - %%~nxf"
    7za a -tzip "%OUTPUT_DIR%\%%~nz.zip" ".\%%~nz\*"
)
```

And, since you are using `-e` instead of `-x`, I assume your zip archives are flat, that is they don't have repeating filenames in subdirectories.

Comment: To check for directory existence you should use a trailing backslash e.g. `if not exist "%%~nz\" md "%%~nz"`.

Comment: @wolfrevokcats, when I save this as a batch file and run it, all it does it create a folder of the zipped folder name.

Comment: Do you see  `output` directory appearing in the parent directory?

Comment: Yes, the output folder appears in the parent directory but I need it to appear in the same directory.

Comment: That would definitely be wrong. Consider the situation when one of the zip files has the same name as the output directory. Archiver will then try to archive already archived things.  That will lead to a mess.  If you want to keep all the files in one place you'd better move your zip files into `input` subdirectory and run the batch from there.  Don't forget to delete *newly produced* files/directories before every run.

Comment: Wolfrevokcats, would it be easier to have a batch file that unzips the file within a zipped folder and renames the contents "zipped folder name" & "_" & "File Name"  and places the file in the same level as the zipped folder? I could work with the files that way.

Comment: @ZacharyMcClurg Again there will be a mess if one of `"zipped folder name" & "_" & "File Name"` accidentally matches some of the input zip archives. I strongly recommend keeping input and output files separately.  This is a one off operation, isn't it?  And also if you have multiple files in an archive you will get multiple output archives per input archive. I doubt that this is what you want.

Comment: That method also sounds as if it will create a cyclic issue, whereby the newly zipped file would be added back into the `for` loops `*.zip` wildcard and reprocessed over and over again until something goes horribly wrong!